# PHP closures & callbacks

Tags: php, function, callback, closures

I'm learning closures but I'm stuck with this:

```
function addPrefix($string) {
    return function($prefix) use ($string) {
        echo $prefix.$string;
    };
}
$randomstring = "a test";
$c = addPrefix($randomstring);
echo $c("This is ");
```

Why is $prefix concatenated? It's not even called as an argument, I just don't get it.

Comment: `$prefix` is concatenated to `$string`, because that is the intent of the outer function, `addPrefix`, and if it is not declared as an argument, must be because it is declared somewhere else in the same scope as the outer function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pay attention in your example there is 2 functions. addPrefix, and an anonymous function it addPrefix returns.

So, `$c` is this anonymous function (returned by addPrefix), which has the $prefix argument.